# Preposition of 'auf' when translating "man plays the drums" into German

Tags: preposition

> "Der Mann spielt auf der Trommel."

What does auf mean on the sentence? From previous examples of auf's usage, I'd guess it means 'on' ? On the drums? That doesn't make much sense... so what's the correct meaning of 'auf' here?

Comment: "Er spielt Trommel/die Trommel" = "He is a drummer"; "Er spielt auf der Trommel" = "He is currently drumming".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sentence is ok, but feels incomplete; it is missing the object of *what* is being played on the drum. Without such object one would usually phrase it like:

> Der Mann spielt Trommel (The man plays drums)

In English it's the same usage really. If you specify what is being played; then you also play on the drum (stressing that it is not played on the violin, the guitar or whatever):

> Der Mann spielt auf der Trommel einen Marsch (The man plays a march on the drums).

Comment: I don't recognize the claimed incompleteness: There is no checklist for mandatory information and e. g. the time of day is not mentioned either.

Comment: @guidot The sentence is ok. Yet usage *usually* is "Jemand spielt XY" where XY is being played. XY can be an instrument, a song, or even something else like a game, enacting another person or animal etc. And if you want to specify the means, you amend that with "auf / mit der Trommel" etc. It doesn't mean you cannot use it in other context, but this is IMHO the most common usage.

Comment: @guidot I agree with planetmaker. If somebody says to me: "Der Mann spielt auf der Trommel" I feel the impulse to ask: "Und was spielt er?" - thinking about someone sitting on a drum and playing Candy Crush on his phone ;-)
But this may be a regional thing :-)